# How to get submited form in action?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this HTML5 code:

```
   <form id="LogInArea"  action = "/Home/ValidateUser" >
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login Page</legend>
        <p>
        <label>
            User name<br>
            <input type="text" id="userName" required></label></p>
        <p><label>
            Password<br>
            <input type="password" id="password" required></label></p>
        <p>@*<button id="LoginButton">
            Log in</button>*@
            <button>submit</button>
            </p>
        <a href="/Home/RegisterPage">Register</a> if you don't have an account.
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

When I press the **submit** button the ValidateUser() action in Home controller is fired.

My question is how can I get the submitted form in ValidateUser() action and how I get the values of form element?

P.S. I don't want to use model!

Comment: Create a model with properties `UserName` and `Password`. Declare it in your view - `@model yourAssemby.yourModel` and use strongly typed html helpers to bind to your properties - `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)` and post back to `public ActionResult ValidateUser(yourModel model)`. Suggest you go to the MVC site and work through the basic tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you don't want to use a model as the other answers recommend, however you can get the form values by using the `Request` object.

```
[HttpPost]
public void ValidateUser()
{
    string name = Request.Form["userName"];
    string password = Request.Form["password"];
}
```

However you will need ensure that you set your form method to Post and add name values to all your submitted form fields.

```
<form id="LogInArea"  action = "/Home/ValidateUser" method="post">
    ...
    <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" required></label>
    ...
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required></label>
    ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also define a value for the 'name' attribute, so instead of:

```
<input type="text" id="userName" required>
```

it should be

```
<input type="text" id="userName" name="username" required>
```

then in your controller:

```
public ActionResult ValidateUser(string username)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to catch model you passed into your view i.e.

If you have passed `Login` model into your view, then you have to catch same into your controller's action method like below:

```
public ActionResult Login(Login model)
{
    // Login is your model which you passed into view. Validate it here.
}
```

To get values you have to use name attribute in your input tag.
Let me know if you have any confusion.